# Сброс настройки маршрутизатора SilkWorm 3250

Tags: настройки, маршрутизатор

Нужно взломать (или сбросить) или восстановить пароли маршрутизатора `SilkWorm 3250` на `WinXP`. На оф сайте есть способ восстановления пароля на Линуксе.

Answer (score 1):

> На оф сайте есть способ восстановления пароля на Линуксе.

Приведите ссылку на способ восстановления.

Посмотрите вот здесь: [Восстановления паролей к Brocade Silkworm switches 4100](http://clck.ru/1Mo-t). В вашем случае, там где идет речь про загрузку в привилегированном режиме. Или еще один момент искать заводской пароль.

Comment: http://user-techdocs.blogspot.com/2010/12/brocade-password-recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

В руках подобный аппарат не держал, но не уж то нету кнопки "ресет" ?

Comment: неа, нету кнопки.